# In table add scroll to all column except first one

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have table on my screen which contains many column .

One column is of employee name and others are times list.  i want to put scrolll-bar to only time list . employee name should not scroll.

[image]

**CSS::**

```
.fc-view {
 width: 100%; /* needed for view switching (when view is absolute) */
 overflow-x:scroll;
 overflow
  }
```

**HTML::**

```
<div class="well" id="cal"><div id='calendar' class="fc"></div>
</div>-y:hidden;
```

this class contains table>.

Comment: apply overflow: auto; instead of scroll.

Comment: @cVplZ actually i failed to solve this issue ...and requirements changed so dint implemented that part .

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
#employee-names { overflow: hidden; }

#times-list { overflow: scroll; }
```

You'll have to target the right ID's # for the divs your using though. But that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Pranay Rana's trick do the work

```
<div style="overflow-x : scroll">
```